# Convert DATA to Date

Tags: swift, macos, nsdate, nsdata

I am trying to get last used date of a file using NSFileManager, i am getting the date in NSData format but i am not sure how to convert Data to Date.

I am getting below values from NSFileManager

```
key : "com.apple.lastuseddate#PS"
value : <b9b6c35e 00000000 abd73225 00000000>
```

Please let me know on how to convert above Data value to Date.

I used below function to convert data to date but i am getting completely wrong values.

> ```
> func dataToDate(data:Data) -> Date{
>     let components = NSDateComponents()
>     let bytes = [uint8](data)
>     components.year   = Int(bytes[0] | bytes[1] << 8)
>     components.month  = Int(bytes[2])
>     components.day    = Int(bytes[3])
>     components.hour   = Int(bytes[4])
>     components.minute = Int(bytes[5])
>     components.second = Int(bytes[6])
>
>     let calendar = NSCalendar.current
>     return calendar.date(from: components as DateComponents)!
> }
> ```

Edit:
@Martin R, below is the code which i used to get the data.

```
var attributes:[FileAttributeKey : Any]?
do{
    attributes = try FileManager.default.attributesOfItem(atPath: url.path)
}catch{
    print("Issue getting attributes of file")
}

if let extendedAttr = attributes![FileAttributeKey(rawValue: "NSFileExtendedAttributes")] as? [String : Any]{
    let data = extendedAttr["com.apple.lastuseddate#PS"] as? Data
}
```

Comment: Can you print the individual bytes of the data, if the data is only a few bytes? This way we can try to figure out what format the data is in. That said, you can always try `NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(data) as! Date`.

Comment: Check [this](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/language/how-to-use-iso-8601-dates-with-jsondecoder-and-codable) article. Basically, you can use a `JSONDecder` and set its `dateDecodingStrategy` to the appropriate value.

Comment: @Sweeper: You can see the individual bytes at `value : <b9b6c35e 00000000 abd73225 00000000>`

Comment: @MartinR That is such a confusing way of writing bytes... Why would they group it like that? I totally thought it is some kind of address...

Comment: @Sweeper: That is how `NSData` was printed in Objective-C. I assume that the actual value is NSData but bridged to Data for Swift. – An address would have 8 bytes, not 16.

Comment: It would still be interesting to see the code which produces this value.

Comment: @MartinR, i added my code where i am getting data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The necessary information can be found in [Data to different types ?](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/116739) in the Apple Developer Forum.

First note that it is unsafe to rely on undocumented extended attributes. A better way to get the same result is to retrieve the `NSMetadataItemLastUsedDateKey` from an `NSMetadataItem`:

```
if let date = NSMetadataItem(url: url)?.value(forAttribute: NSMetadataItemLastUsedDateKey) as? Date {
    print(date)
}
```

But to answer your actual question: That extended attribute holds a
 UNIX `struct timespec` (compare [`<time.h>`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/time.h.html)) value. That is the type used for `st_atimespec` and other members of `struct stat` (which in turn is the type used with `fstat()` and similar system calls).

You have to copy the data into a `timespec` value, compute the seconds from the `tv_sec` and `tv_nsec` members, and then create a `Date` from the seconds since the Unix epoch.

```
func dataToDate(data: Data) -> Date {
    var ts = timespec()
    precondition(data.count >= MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: ts))
    _ = withUnsafeMutableBytes(of: &ts, { lastuseddata.copyBytes(to: $0)} )
    let seconds = TimeInterval(ts.tv_sec) + TimeInterval(ts.tv_nsec)/TimeInterval(NSEC_PER_SEC)
    return Date(timeIntervalSince1970: seconds)
}
```

Example (your data):

```
let lastuseddata = Data([0xb9, 0xb6, 0xc3, 0x5e, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
                         0xab, 0xd7, 0x32, 0x25, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00])

print(dataToDate(data: lastuseddata))
// 2020-05-19 10:36:41 +0000
```

Comment: Thank you for your wonderful answer. I used NSMetadataItem(url: url)? as you mentioned and i am able to get the last used date.